# Eclipse Plugin Development Questions

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I´ve got some questions which shouldn´t be hard for a plugin developer.

- My Plugin should read an INI File and then put the strings into a list. So how do I read a INI File in PDE is there any class? A example code would be amazing.
- Further on I´m using Grid Layout, but I don´t know how I can control the columns. I have to set it at the beginning with:

`layout.numColumns = 3;`

But how do I change the row for a added control? (Button first row, text second row, list third row)

- How can I add when I´m using GridLayout a vertical Scrollbar for my Listbox. It does not work for me in a GridLayout with the following code:

  `List listbox = new List(newproject, SWT.BORDER | SWT.SINGLE | SWT.V_SCROLL);`

  `Rectangle clientArea = getShell().getClientArea ();`

  `SAFETYVersions.setBounds (clientArea.x, clientArea.y, 100, 100);`

I think when I´m using GridLayout i also have to define the size of the listbox?

-Last thing is there a simple checkbox in the widget library from SWT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My Plugin should read an INI File and then put the strings into a list. So how do I read a INI File in PDE is there any class? A example code would be amazing.

Take a look at the `IFile` interface.

> Further on I´m using Grid Layout, but I don´t know how I can control the columns.

You use `SWT.PUSH` to put the widgets onto the Grid Layout.  If `layout.numColumns = 3;`, that's 3 pushes for each row.

If you want a more complicated layout than a simple grid, you have to use `Composites` to group the widgets.

> Last thing is there a simple checkbox in the widget library from SWT?

Yes, it's a `Button` with a `SWT.CHECK` style.

Comment: With the IFile it is possible to read a file via a stream. Isn´t there any solution for INI files to make it more flexibel. There are so many things included in the PDE is there no such thing like ReadINIFile(Section,EntryName)? If so it would be to easy :) `label = new Label(newproject, SWT.NULL);
  label.setText("");` That´s how I create a new line til now just by pushing enough empty labels is there a better way? My widgets are grouped with a Composite and I´m using a gridlayout additional is that would you mentioned?

Comment: SWT.PUSH ist for buttons etc. not for pushing a control onto the layout?

Comment: @Nautis:  You're right,  I had the Swing push on my mind when I wrote that.

Comment: @Nautis.  Eclipse plugins generally don't use INI files.  There are classes and methods for dealing with XML property files, which is the type of property files used by Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

About listbox size, try following:

```
GridData gd = new GridData();
gd.heightHint = 100;
gd.widthHint = 100;
listbox.setLayoutData(gd);
```

listbox should be in GridLayout, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use a property file instead.
Check out the java.util.Properties for more details.
You have everything there to help you out.

Drop me a line if you have problems and i will write a quick blog post for this at my blog.

Geirr

Comment: I´m creating a plug in for a new project wizard. Isn´t it mandatory to use the newwizardpage?